# May one place letters under one another as long as there is a space between them?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, aleph-bet-letters, torah-writing, tractate-soferim

Soferim 2:2 rules that one must put a line-width space between lines, a letter-width space between words, and a hair-width space between letters.

Certain letters leave much space beneath them, and others may extend into that gap. For instance, a yud leaves space underneath for, say, a beis to extend underneath it:

[image]

Does that make the scroll passul, or do the letters need to be strictly next to one another?

Comment: No that's still not a good example. In that case that's straight up two words. We define the space in between by the top line. You want something like צ or נ where the leg bends back but the tops can still be lines up.

Comment: @doubleaa How is that two words? Take the word ריב for example, in Bereishis 13:7. (If it's the space at the top, how can there be any such case?)

Comment: You made a really big Ekev on that Bet (the Ekev isn't even an integral part of the letter). In ריב the Ekev should be short enough that there isn't a full letter space at the top.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps I didn't make a perfect sketch. But if i just need a hairsbreadth between the yud and beis, while I need more than that for the ekev...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the general psak it is not a psul, although not mehudar, 
See מ'ב סימן לב ס'ק קיב

> אם בתחלת הכתיבה ממשיך רגל התחתון של הנו”ן והצד”י וכותב האות הסמוכה לתוכה כגון פני או ארצי כשר כיון דבתיבה אחת נכתבו ומ”מ לכתחלה אין נכון לעשות כן להבליע אות בתוך אות כי יש מחמירין בזה:

עירוב אותיות according to the רמב"ן is the case you are describing, according to him it would be a psul, if they are really swallowed  (worse than your image), however the other rishonim learn עירוב אותיות as דיבוקים  (not מוקף גויל).

If there is part of a letter that causes the other letter to loose its צורה than it is possul according to all as the שוע says

>
כח. יש ליזהר שלא יכנס ראש הלמ”ד באויר הה”א או החי”ת אפילו בלא נגיעה:

And מב קלב

> אם נכנס כ”כ בענין שנשתנה צורת האות שתינוק דלא חכים ולא טיפש אם נכסה לו שיטה התחתונה שלא יהא נראה רק ראש הלמ”ד ולא גוף הלמ”ד לא יכיר האות מה הוא הוי שינוי צורת האות ופסול [וגם לא יצוייר בו תיקון משום שלא כסדרן] וכ”ש אם נכנס ראש הלמ”ד בתוך חלל ד’ או רי”ש ונראית כה”א דפסול ואינו מועיל בזה קריאת התינוק כהוגן שהרי עינינו רואות שנשתנה עי”ז לאות אחר

Also one should write on the שרטוט or according to some within at least a שעורה of the שרטוט.